# Segmentation of a big raster

Tags: raster, r, clustering, image-segmentation

I'm trying to convert one raster into a SpatialPolygons. I've got a big raster (12 millions pixels) with a lot of zeros, and some negative values (representing some depression in a DEM). I would like to cluster all these negatives values into polygons, to get a map of all the depressions on my map.

I'm a R beginner and I can't find a suitable function to do the job.

Does anyone have a clue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tool (part of the raster & rgeos libraries) that you need to consider is:

```
output_shp <- rasterToPolygons(x, fun=function(x){x<0}, n=4, na.rm=TRUE, digits=12, dissolve=TRUE)
```

Where 'x' is your DEM-raster.
This results in a 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame', which is what you were after.

However, before you run the rasterToPolygons-tool, it would be advisable to reclassify your DEM into -1s and 0s:

```
reclassified_raster <- reclassify(x,c(-Inf,0,-1, 0,Inf,1))
```

This will give you a raster with all the negative values as '-1' and all positive values as '0', for use in the rasterToPolygons-tool. If this step is not taken, then every height in the elevation model will become its own polygon.

Comment: Yes I saw this tool but it's for 4,8 o 16 nodes polygons only. I got some very complex and big polygons to create.

Comment: Moreover, this method would take several days to create my polygons, if it can do it..

Comment: Have you tried with dissolve=TRUE ?

Comment: Otherwise, you could also consider the GDAL implementation - see http://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html - although this turns everything into polygons, not just the bits you want, unless you also use a mask layer.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to set all the negatives pixels to -1, in order to generate these polygons ?

Comment: Yes. You can do that.

Comment: And how ? I'm very new in R. Do I have to create a loop to do this pixel per pixel ?